# Using pthread in a MPI program has a Compilation error

Tags: c++, compilation, pthreads, mpi

I'm trying to run an MPI program that uses pthreads. I am able to compile and run in my local machine but couldn't do that on a server.

This is the command I used to compile.

```
target1: TARGET=main
target2: TARGET=kmer_finaliser

CC = mpic++
# CPPFLAGS = -pg 
# CPPFLAGS = -lm -g -Wall -pthread
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 -pthread

USER_LIBS = -I /home/ruchin/sparsehash-sparsehash-2.0.4/src 

main: main.o extractor.o com.o kmer_dump.o thread_pool.o
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o kmer_counter.out main.o extractor.o com.o kmer_dump.o thread_pool.o $(USER_LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp extractor.h com.h kmer_dump.h thread_pool.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c main.cpp $(USER_LIBS)

kmer_finaliser: kmer_finaliser.o kmer_dump.o
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o kmer_finaliser.out kmer_finaliser.o kmer_dump.o $(USER_LIBS)

kmer_finaliser.o: kmer_finaliser.cpp kmer_dump.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c kmer_finaliser.cpp $(USER_LIBS)

extractor.o: extractor.cpp extractor.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c extractor.cpp $(USER_LIBS)

com.o: com.cpp com.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c com.cpp $(USER_LIBS)

kmer_dump.o: kmer_dump.cpp kmer_dump.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c kmer_dump.cpp $(USER_LIBS)

thread_pool.o: thread_pool.cpp kmer_dump.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c thread_pool.cpp $(USER_LIBS)
```

This is the error I get.

```
/usr/bin/ld: thread_pool.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please post the full command line

Comment: This is the make file that I use, here I used -lpthread flag also. didn't work. also like @francesco suggested added -fopenmp flag. didn't work that either

Comment: Did you remove all the object files and run `make` again with `-pthread` ?

Comment: There is a bit of confusion on the flags.```CPPFLAGS``` and ```USER_LIBS``` are intended only for the source file. To link the executable main you need linker flags, say ```LDFLAGS="-lpthread"```. Then the recipe for main and kmer_finalizer should be something like ```$(CC) -o outfile obj.o obj2.o ... $(LDFLAGS)```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page of g++](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html), you should include also in the compilation the flag `-pthread`:

> -pthread
> Define additional macros required for using the POSIX threads
> library.  You should use this option consistently for both
> compilation and linking.  This option is supported on
> GNU/Linux targets, most other Unix derivatives, and also on
> x86 Cygwin and MinGW targets.

Comment: I tried -pthread, but when I add that flag I get different compilation errors. "undefined reference to `ompi_mpi_comm_world`" is one of them.

Comment: @RuchinAmaratunga Try to add ```-fopenmp```